# How to force method inside IQueryable to evaluate?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm trying to construct complex LINQ query without executing it. Right now it looks like this:

```
// model is EF database context, and Runs/Labs are tables in this database, labNames is array of strings
var sortedGroupsQuery = model.Runs.Where(modelRun =>
                labNames.Select(lab => model.Labs.FirstOrDefault(modelLab => modelLab.name == lab).id).Contains(modelRun.lab_id.Value)
                && modelRun.scenarios.name.StartsWith("Full"))
            .SortByBuildNumberAndId(ShowMasterBranchOnly)
            .GroupBy(modelRun => modelRun.lab_id)
            .Select(group => group.AsQueryable().SortByBuildNumberAndId(ShowMasterBranchOnly));
```

`SortByBuildNumberAndId` looks like this:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<AutotestResultService.Runs> SortByBuildNumberAndId(
            this IQueryable<AutotestResultService.Runs> query, bool showMasterBranchOnly) =>
            showMasterBranchOnly
                ? query.Where(modelRun => modelRun.build_number != "NO BUILD NUMBER")
                    .OrderByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.build_number)
                    .ThenByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.id)
                : query.OrderByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.id);
```

When I try to materialize query in `sortedGroupsQuery` I get the following error:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[AutotestResultService.Runs]
>   SortByBuildNumberAndId(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AutotestResultService.Runs],
>   Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression."

I need to sort contents of each group. How do I force it to evaluate `SortByBuildNumberAndId` call to a `Where` and `OrderBy` calls?

**Edit**

If I remove last `Select` call, query works fine. That `SortByBuildNumberAndId` works fine when called after `Where`, but for some reason won't work inside `Select`. Is there a way to fix this? All I need is to sort or filter group contents based on bool variable value.

**Edit 2**

This also works, meaning that `SortByBuildNumberAndId` itself is correct:

```
var sortedGroupsQuery = model.Runs.Where(modelRun =>
                    labNames.Select(lab => model.Labs.FirstOrDefault(modelLab => modelLab.name == lab).id)
                        .Contains(modelRun.lab_id.Value)
                    && modelRun.scenarios.name.StartsWith("Full"))
                //.ApplyFilters(ShowMasterBranchOnly, BuildNumber, ShowVDP)
                .SortByBuildNumberAndId(ShowMasterBranchOnly)
                .GroupBy(modelRun => modelRun.lab_id)
                .Select(group => group.AsQueryable()
                    .Where(modelRun => modelRun.build_number != "NO BUILD NUMBER")
                    .OrderByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.build_number)
                    .ThenByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.id));
```

**Edit 3:**
For testing purposes, I tried adding this:

```
public static IQueryable<AutotestResultService.Runs> SortByBuildNumberAndId(
    this IQueryable<AutotestResultService.Runs> query) =>
    true
        ? query.Where(modelRun => modelRun.build_number != "NO BUILD NUMBER")
            .OrderByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.build_number)
            .ThenByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.id)
        : query.OrderByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.id);
```

And this:

```
public static IQueryable<AutotestResultService.Runs> SortByBuildNumberAndId(
            this IQueryable<AutotestResultService.Runs> query) =>
                query.Where(modelRun => modelRun.build_number != "NO BUILD NUMBER")
                    .OrderByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.build_number)
                    .ThenByDescending(modelRun => modelRun.id);
```

Both won't work with same error:

```
var sortedGroupsQuery = model.Runs.Where(modelRun =>
                    labNames.Select(lab => model.Labs.FirstOrDefault(modelLab => modelLab.name == lab).id)
                        .Contains(modelRun.lab_id.Value)
                    && modelRun.scenarios.name.StartsWith("Full"))
                .SortByBuildNumberAndId(ShowMasterBranchOnly)
                .GroupBy(modelRun => modelRun.lab_id)
                .Select(group => group.AsQueryable().SortByBuildNumberAndId());
```

Comment: The question in your title would answer to "with appending .ToList()", or applying "foreach", you would force an IQuerieable to Execute.
But the content of your question seems to deal with other problems.
Maybe your "SortByBuiltNumberAndID" should return an IQueryable, remove the "ordered".

Comment: @Holger Tried it, getting same error.

Comment: Does it work if you put the `Where` and `Order By` expressions in the `sortedGroupsQuery` instead of in the function?

Comment: Ah, you have two calls to SortByBuildNumberAndId and the second fails ?
What has this "AsQueryable" to do there ? It should work without that, if you don't want to execute anything.
Sorting twice makes no sense anyway.

Comment: @ShirazA It works, yes.

Comment: I think the problem could be the boolean parameter to `SortByBuildNumberAndId`. try removing that. It can't use that boolean inside the second call to the function, because it probably evaluate that into a query.

Comment: @Holger Removing first SortByBuildNumberAndId makes no difference, I'm still getting same error. I'm calling AsQueryable() to match SortByBuildNumberAndId signature, which I'd rather avoid changing.

Comment: @ShirazA. see edit 3, makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should build the query instead of trying to define it all at once.

```
Main
{
   var query = model.Runs.Where(...);
   query = AddSortLogic(query);
   var finalQuery = query.GroupBy(...).Select(...);
}

private IQueryable<Runs> AddSortLogic(IQueryable<Runs> query)
{
   if(ShowMasterBranchOnly)
   {
      query = query.Where(...)
         .SortBy(...)
         .ThenBy(...);
   }
   else
   {
      query = query.SortBy(...);
   }
   return query;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, even saved every step to a new variable, still getting same error in the end. Problem is that `SortByBuildNumberAndId` refuses to work inside `Select`

Comment: @user2363676 If you're putting this inside a select anywhere, you're not implementing this version correctly.  Your function is not a select, and should not be treated as one.  Here, we are passing the query around and adding to it.

Comment: I tried passing it around and adding to it. Query stops working at the last step, when I add `Select` call, and I need it because I need to filter/order contents of each group I get from `GroupBy`.

Comment: You want groups of ordered items, right ?
If you want to filter, filter first, and than do the grouping, also for performance reasons. You group first, and then you throw grouping results away ....
Second: Order only once, not before and after grouping, this makes no sense.
According to this: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/10530806/linq-group-by-then-order-groups-of-result The ordering inside the select should work.
But as I said the AsQueryable can impossibly be converted to SQL.
Kyles approach looks good to, he is sorting before grouping, There is no need for a final Select.